# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.android.server.autofill.RemoteFillService$PendingRequest.cancel()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, crashlytics-android

I am getting crash in `Firebase` crashlytics

Same question i fond [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385623/null-pointer-exception-on-boolean-com-android-server-autofill-remotefillservice) but in that also not getting solution.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean 
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1973)
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1913)
android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.reportAssistContextExtras 
(IActivityManager.java:8307)
arrow_right
android.app.ActivityThread.handleRequestAssistContextExtras 
(ActivityThread.java:3210)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage 
(ActivityThread.java:1913)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6942)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(Zygote.java:327)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Can anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please, share also source code where this error occurs.

Comment: @ferran i have only above log which i font in firebase crashlytics list, this error is not coming from my code

Comment: Yes, but this happens when you are doing something in your code. This part of code could be useful to find the issue. Or does it happens at launch?

Comment: i am not able to replicate this issue, i am getting error in  firebase crashlytics list

Comment: I have the same problem, I am see this error in firebase crashlytics, none of my code is inside the stack trace.

Comment: I also see this in crashlytics would love to know what the resolution is